# Which style transition/threshold do I need for carpeted stairs to meet floor boards?

Tags: carpet

I've had a new carpet installed on my stairs.

The fitter wasn't able to supply a threshold and I wasn't at home at the time of the install so I couldn't ask him what style I needed.

Is there a specific curvature/style/design name that I should be using for this scenario?

[image: My new carpet]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm no pro, but that lip at the top of the stairs gives me the heebie-jeebies, and I don't know that a transition would help. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation would be to terminate the carpet on the last riser.  If you put in a threshold, yes you'll protect the end of the carpet, but you'll still have a lip for people to trip over and fall.  Not fun.

If your flooring has no terminal piece at the top of the stairs, you can certainly get pre-shaped "noses" with proper support built into the shape.

Answer (score 1):

Your home builder's store will have a variety of thresholds in many colors and materials. Which ever on you pick out make sure you screw it down into the wood floor. You don't want it loosening up since it's at the tp of the stairs.

Maybe something like this..... but in one piece naturally.

[image]